# Query Mongo for multiple key value pair combinations in array field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to query for Mongo documents based on 1 many key value pairs over a large collection of documents.

I am storing the values in an array called descriptors. I cannot figure out to write the query to consistently return results.

Basically I am trying to write the following SQL query in Mongo

```
 select * from descriptors where 
    (id=123 and value="Latest based on new infor")
  or 
    (id=3221 and value="Latest new info")
```

I have tried the following:

```
db.collection.find({$or: [
       {  descriptors:
         {
          '$elemMatch':
            {
               id: 123,
               value: 'Latest based on new infor',

            }
         }
       },
       {  descriptors:
        {
          '$elemMatch':
            {
               id: 3221,
               value: 'Latest new info',

            }
        }
       }
    ]
}
```

Here are sample documents.

```
{ 
        "_id" : ObjectId("569d62673b020a47f0401325"), 

        "descriptors" : [
            {
                "id" : 123, 
                "name" : "Version", 
                "value" : "Latest based on new infor", 
                "parent" : null
            }, 
            {
                "id" : 345, 
                "name" : "Eligibility Criteria", 
                "value" : "Really qualified ", 
                "parent" : null
            }
        ],      
    }

    { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("569dac2e4e6247c01bbac47f"), 

        "descriptors" : [
            {
                "id" : 3221, 
                "name" : "Version", 
                "value" : "Latest new info", 
                "parent" : null
            }, 
            {
                "id" : 345, 
                "name" : "Eligibility Criteria", 
                "value" : "Different Value", 
                "parent" : null
            }
        ], 
    }

    { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("56bce4df7aae8369d8fc705d"), 
        "descriptors" : [
            {
                "id" : 3221, 
                "name" : "Version", 
                "value" : "Latest based on new infor", 
                "parent" : null
            }, 
            {
                "id" : 345.0, 
                "name" : "Eligibility Criteria", 
                "value" : "Really qualified", 
                "parent" : null
            }
        ], 

    }
```

Any help would be appreciated,
gsvi

Comment: Did you try https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/find/ ?

Comment: sorry forgot to include the query that works part of the time.

Comment: np, so why you are not happy with your query? It returns first 2 documents. Seems okay to me.

Comment: thanks. I noticed that something was wrong in the documents in the database since I posted. you helped me by confirming the query was correct.